# Rx DotNet - Chaining observables with threading

Tags: c#, xamarin, reactive-programming, system.reactive

I'm trying to introduce Rx in my Xamarin mobile app and I'd like to chain a sequence of calls during my login phase on app startup.

> **TL;DR;** How do I run 2 / 3 observables one after the other to retrieve data and setup threading properly.

More in detail I perform the following:

1. Login the User and retrieve related data `LoginUser() : IObservable<User>`
2. Based on User's type the ID to either `RetrieveRemoteA() : IObservable<A>` or `RetrieveRemoteB() : IObservable<B>`
3. Once data are available (either of type `A` or `B`), I update the UI.

This is a sort of diagram to describe the flow (explained above):

[image]

Considering that I want to avoid calling new observables (sources) from within the `Subscribe()` of the previous one, this is what I've implemente for retrieving my data and update the UI (the flow in the image has been serialized in the code below).

```
IObservable<User> loginUserObservable = LogInUser(currentUser);

loginUserObservable
    .SubscribeOn(ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
    .SelectMany(
        (user) =>
        {
            if (user.Type == UserType.A)
                return RetrieveRemoteA(user.UserId); // outputs IObservable<A>

            return Observable.Return(new A());
        },
        (user, a) =>
        {
            B b = null;
            return new { user, a, b }; // Create anonymous type to keet track of 'user'
        })
    .SelectMany(
        (xType) =>
        {
            if (xType.user.Type == UserType.B)
                return RetrieveRemoteB(xType.user.UserId); // outputs IObservable<B>

            return Observable.Return(new B());
        },
        (xType, bData) =>
        {
            var user = xType.user;
            var a = xType.a;
            var b = b;

            return new { user, a, b };
        })
    .ObserveOn(ImmediateScheduler.Instance)
    .Select((xType) =>
    {
        if (xType.user.Type == UserType.A)
        {
            A a = xType.a;
            B b = null;
            return new { a, b };
        }
        else {
            A a = null;
            B b = xType.b;
            return new { a, b };
        }
    })
    .Subscribe((result) =>
    {
        if (result.a != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ID: {result.a.Id}");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine($"ID: {result.b.Id}");
        }
    });
```

Once running, it seems that the flow get stacked within `RetrieveRemoteA(user.UserId)`, even if the method finishes without errors.

```
public IObservable<A> RetrieveRemoteA(string userId)
{
    return Observable.FromAsync<A>(async () =>
    {
        A a = await CustomAPI(userId) 
        return a;
    }
}
```

When I implement the flow sequentially by calling each new observable within the Subscribe of the previous one, it works properly (but it is not the right way to do it).

I think this is an issue with Threads or either with a wrong Rx implementation of mine.

Do you have any clue, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're wanting to do is really quite easy using the `Observable.Amb` operator. It's job is to allow two observables to run, but once one returns a value then ignore the other one.

Here's how to write your query:

```
var query =
    from user in loginUserObservable
    let a_observable = user.Type == UserType.A ? RetrieveRemoteA(user.UserId) : Observable.Never<A>()
    let b_observable = user.Type == UserType.B ? RetrieveRemoteB(user.UserId) : Observable.Never<B>()
    from ab in
        Observable
            .Amb(
                a_observable.Select(x => new { a = x, b = (B)null }),
                b_observable.Select(x => new { a = (A)null, b = x }))
    select ab;
```

That's it.

Given this sample data you can have a play:

```
var currentUser = "";

IObservable<User> LogInUser(string cu) => Observable.Start(() => new User() { Type = UserType.A, UserId = "Z1" });
IObservable<A> RetrieveRemoteA(string id) => Observable.Start(() => new A() { Id = "A.Z2" });
IObservable<B> RetrieveRemoteB(string id) => Observable.Start(() => new B() { Id = "B.Z3" });

IObservable<User> loginUserObservable = LogInUser(currentUser);

/* put `query` here */

query
    .Subscribe(x =>
        Console.WriteLine($@"ID: {(x.a != null ? x.a.Id : x.b.Id)}"));
```

---

Alternatively, you could just avoid the `Amb` operator entirely by doing this simple query:

```
var query =
    from user in loginUserObservable
    from ab in
        user.Type == UserType.A
            ? RetrieveRemoteA(user.UserId).Select(x => new { a = x, b = (B)null })
            : RetrieveRemoteB(user.UserId).Select(x => new { a = (A)null, b = x })
    select ab;
```